# How to check method is present in action or not in freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

I want to check if action contains method or not in my freemarker(ftl) file but it seems there is no way. FTL supports to check for variable and macro but not action method. It seems weird to me.

e.g.

```
[#if action.hasMethodPresent()??]
     ${action.hasMethodPresent()}
[/#if]
```

Above code snippet is giving template error. May be there will be other way to achieve this but I am not sure. Appreciate relevant answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `[#if action.hasMethodPresent??]`. Because, if you put `()` there, then you tell FreeMarker to call the method and check if it has a (non-`null`) return value.

Comment: @ddekany What if my function is equally named to a parameter in the same class? As `??` can also check for an attributes' existance this would conflict right?

Comment: @SimonBaars I'm not sure what do you mean by "parameter" in a class. If a filed, then by default FreeMarker doesn't expose fields, so that shouldn't cause any confusion.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant field indeed. I was confused by the accepted answer on the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41099386/freemarker-cast-interface-object-to-the-real-concret-class. It shows the use of `??` to check for a fields' existance.

Comment: @SimonBaars I don't see the answer saying "field", but anyway, if FreeMarker is configured to expose Java fields, it might as well checks that. From the view point of the template language there are just subvariables (like `bar` in `foo.bar`), and it can check if they have a non-`null` value. It doesn't know what a subvariable maps to on the Java side (that depends on the `ObjectWrapper` used).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write `${(action.hasMethodPresent())!}`